# Maximum number of characters using keystrokes A, Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V

Tags: algorithm

This is an interview question from google. I am not able to solve it by myself. Can somebody shed some light?

Write a program to print the sequence of keystrokes such that it generates the maximum number of character 'A's. You are allowed to use only 4 keys: <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Only N keystrokes are allowed. All <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ characters are considered as one keystroke, so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is one keystroke.

For example, the sequence <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> generates two A's in 4 keystrokes.

- Ctrl+A is Select All
- Ctrl+C is Copy
- Ctrl+V is Paste

I did some mathematics. For any N, using x numbers of A's , one <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, one <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and y <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, we can generate max ((N-1)/2)<sup>2</sup> number of A's. For some N > M, it is better to use as many <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>'s, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> sequences as it doubles the number of A's.

The sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will not overwrite the existing selection. It will append the copied selection to selected one.

Comment: In many text editors `^A` is usually "select all", `^C` is "copy", `^V` is "paste". Does that give you an idea?

Comment: I mean number of 'A's. For example, for N=7 we can print 9 A's using keystrokes A, A, A, CTRL+A, CTRL+C, CTRL+V, CTRL+V

Comment: Uh, that's 7 keystrokes.

Comment: @John "All CTRL+ characters are considered as one keystroke, so CTRL+A is one keystroke."

Comment: Are you sure this is a real Google interview question? Might be slightly irrelevant but I am genuinely curious. Were you actually interviewed by Google or just found it on the web? Great read nonetheless: http://www.technologywoman.com/2010/05/17/debunking-the-google-interview-myth/

Comment: C-a, C-c, C-v may be interpreted as commands by some text editors but they are very unlikely to have copy and paste effects when printed from a C++ program in most common execution environments.

Comment: I've removed the C++ tag, this is purely an algorithm question and hopefully it'll prevent unhappy c++ followers to downvote / vote to close.

Comment: @yc Which apparently doesn't work.

Comment: I know that it's not the point, but I'm not sure that you even need to write a program for this; it can be solved algorithmically instead of programmatically.

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-print-maximum-number-of-a-using-given-four-keys/ -> Refer here for some hep on the question

Answer (score 43):

There's a dynamic programming solution. We start off knowing 0 keys can make us 0 A's. Then we iterate through for `i` up to `n`, doing two things: pressing A once and pressing select all + copy followed by paste `j` times (actually `j-i-1` below; note the trick here: the contents are still in the clipboard, so we can paste it multiple times without copying each time). We only have to consider up to 4 consecutive pastes, since select, copy, paste x 5 is equivalent to select, copy, paste, select, copy, paste and the latter is better since it leaves us with more in the clipboard. Once we've reached `n`, we have the desired result.

The complexity might appear to be O(N), but since the numbers grow at an exponential rate it is actually O(N<sup>2</sup>) due to the complexity of multiplying the large numbers. Below is a Python implementation. It takes about 0.5 seconds to calculate for N=50,000.

```
def max_chars(n):
  dp = [0] * (n+1)
  for i in xrange(n):
    dp[i+1] = max(dp[i+1], dp[i]+1) # press a
    for j in xrange(i+3, min(i+7, n+1)):
      dp[j] = max(dp[j], dp[i]*(j-i-1)) # press select all, copy, paste x (j-i-1)
  return dp[n]
```

In the code, `j` represents the total number of keys pressed after our new sequence of keypresses. We already have `i` keypresses at this stage, and 2 new keypresses go to select-all and copy. Therefore we're hitting paste `j-i-2` times. Since pasting adds to the existing sequence of `dp[i]` `A`'s, we need to add `1` making it `j-i-1`. This explains the `j-i-1` in the 2nd-last line.

Here are some results (`n` => number of A's):

- 7 => 9
- 8 => 12
- 9 => 16
- 10 => 20
- 100 => 1391569403904
- 1,000 => 3268160001953743683783272702066311903448533894049486008426303248121757146615064636953144900245
  174442911064952028008546304
- 50,000 => [a very large number!](http://pastebin.com/FPJU3VP2)

I agree with @SB that you should always state your assumptions: Mine is that you don't need to paste twice to double the number of characters. This gets the answer for 7, so unless my solution is wrong the assumption must be right.

In case someone wonders why I'm not checking sequences of the form <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>: The end result will always be the same as <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> which I *do* consider.

Comment: Is that `n => result` or `result => n`? Either way, I think it's wrong. We can type 9 As with 7 keystrokes. If it's `n => result` it's definitely wrong. The number of As you can type cannot be lower than `n`.

Comment: @IVlad It's `n => result`. You say "We can type 9 As with 7 keystrokes", which is what I get. Read the "trick" I just edited in.

Comment: This looks great, except that the question is to find the maximum number of As for a given number of keystrokes, not the minimum number of keystrokes to get a given number of As.

Comment: @marcog - your notation is at least confusing and at most wrong. `n` is the keystrokes you're allowed to use. You have to compute how many As you can type with `n` keystrokes. So `7 => 7` makes no sense.

Comment: @IVlad Sorry, @Andrew pointed out my mistake. This is still fixable as it's the same basic idea. I'll fix it now.

Comment: @Andrew, @Ivlad: Fixed! I do hope the results are correct now? Thanks for pointing my error out and I'm so sorry for misreading!

Comment: Looks right, + 1. Now let's see if someone can get it down to `O(n)` or even `O(1)` :).

Comment: awesome answer.  took me a few min to see what you're doing.  DP is not a strong suit of mine.. perhaps I should play with it a bit more

Comment: Can you please explain `j-i-1`?  j starts at i+3 - is the +3 a S,C,P? also, what happens when i reaches n-1? j iterates from n+2 to n+1.  Is this still valid?

Comment: @Anon Answered your first question in an edit to my answer. The `+3` is indeed SCP. When `i` reaches `n-1`, there won't be any iterations of the `j` loop.

Comment: You can get this to O(n) by realizing that any sequence of `C-a C-c C-v C-v C-v C-v C-v` can be replaced by `C-a C-c C-v C-a C-c C-v C-v` (the multiplier is the same and the copy buffer is larger in the second) and so you need only consider "select-copy-paste" sequences ending in at most 5 pastes.

Comment: @Chris That's the idea behind @Andrew's solution, so I don't really want to poach it.

Comment: @marcog Nah, the idea behind his is that the sequence `C-a C-c C-v C-v C-v` maximizes the multiplier-per-keystroke.

Comment: I think you mean "select, copy, paste x 5 is equivalent to select, copy, paste, **paste,** select, copy, paste".

Comment: After a certain number of 'A's copy and paste will no longer work due to memory overflow :)

Answer (score 42):

By using marcog's solution I found a pattern that starts at `n=16`.  To illustrate this here are the keystrokes for `n=24` up to `n=29`, I replaced ^A with S (select), ^C with C (copy), and ^V with P (paste) for readability:

```
24: A,A,A,A,S,C,P,P,P,S,C,P,P,P,S,C,P,P,P,S,C,P,P,P
       4   *    4    *    4    *    4    *    4     = 1024
25: A,A,A,A,S,C,P,P,P,S,C,P,P,S,C,P,P,S,C,P,P,S,C,P,P
       4   *    4    *   3   *   3   *   3   *   3    = 1296
26: A,A,A,A,S,C,P,P,P,S,C,P,P,P,S,C,P,P,S,C,P,P,S,C,P,P
       4   *    4    *    4    *   3   *   3   *   3    = 1728
27: A,A,A,A,S,C,P,P,P,S,C,P,P,P,S,C,P,P,P,S,C,P,P,S,C,P,P
       4   *    4    *    4    *    4    *   3   *   3    = 2304
28: A,A,A,A,S,C,P,P,P,S,C,P,P,P,S,C,P,P,P,S,C,P,P,P,S,C,P,P
       4   *    4    *    4    *    4    *    4    *   3    = 3072
29: A,A,A,A,S,C,P,P,P,S,C,P,P,P,S,C,P,P,P,S,C,P,P,P,S,C,P,P,P
       4   *    4    *    4    *    4    *    4    *    4     = 4096
```

After an initial 4 As, the ideal pattern is to select, copy, paste, paste, paste and repeat.  This will multiply the number of As by 4 every 5 keystrokes.  If this 5 keystroke pattern cannot consume the remaining keystrokes on its own some number of 4 keystroke patterns (SCPP) consume the final keystrokes, replacing SCPPP (or removing one of the pastes) as necessary.  The 4 keystroke patterns multiply the total by 3 every 4 keystrokes.

Using this pattern here is some Python code that gets the same results as marcog's solution, but is O(1) **edit**: This is actually O(log n) due to exponentiation, thanks to IVlad for pointing that out.

```
def max_chars(n):
  if n <= 15:
    return (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 12, 16, 20, 27, 36, 48, 64, 81)[n]
  e3 = (4 - n) % 5
  e4 = n // 5 - e3
  return 4 * (4 ** e4) * (3 ** e3)
```

**Calculating e3:**
There are always between 0 and 4 SCPP patterns at the end of the keystroke list, for `n % 5 == 4` there are 4, `n % 5 == 1` there are 3, `n % 5 == 2` there are 2, `n % 5 == 3` there are 1, and `n % 5 == 4` there are 0.  This can be simplified to `(4 - n) % 5`.

**Calculating e4:** 
The total number of patterns increases by 1 whenever `n % 5 == 0`, as it turns out this number increases to exactly `n / 5`.  Using floor division we can get the total number of patterns, the total number for `e4` is the total number of patterns minus `e3`.  For those unfamiliar with Python, `//` is the future-proof notation for floor division.

Comment: Nice one! Tested and it works for `n=3000`, so it's probably right. (Pity I'm out of votes today :/)

Comment: +1, very nice. Minor nitpick though: it's not really `O(1)` as exponentiation cannot be done in constant time. It's `O(log n)`.

Comment: @IVlad The numbers grow so fast it's actually even worse than that. `log(max_chars(1000000)) = 277259.1`, takes a few seconds. Still much faster than mine!

Comment: Just return the number in factored form, and you have a proper O(1) algorithm, assuming O(1) time division.

Comment: Actually, the sequence 'SCPPP' will only multiply the number of characters by three: the first paste simply overwrites the selected text.

Comment: @Nick Last line in the question: "The sequence Ctrl+A, Ctrl+V, Ctrl+C will not overwrite the existing selection. It will append the copied selection to selected one."

Comment: Can you please provide any info on how you discovered the pattern and provide comments on getting e3 and e4? I'm not following.. I would really appreciate it.  This stuff is really cool

Comment: @marcog Yes, I didn't notice that. I don't know of any OS that behaves in that fashion, though.

Comment: @Anon The key to the sequence is what I will call the multiplier-per-keystroke (MPK). Just typing an `A` is special. For our first keystroke its MPK is infinite. After typing 3 `A`s its MPK is 
`4/3 = 1.333` and after the 4th `A` it goes down to `5/4 = 1.25`. The sequence SCPPP has the highest possible MPK. That sequence is 5 characters and multiplies the length by 4. It has an MPK of `4^(1/5) = 1.320`. The sequence SCPP has an MPK of `3^(1/4) = 1.316` and the sequence SCPPPP has an MPK of `5^(1/6) = 1.308`, etc. Note that we start doing SCPPP after the MPK for A has dropped below 1.320.

Comment: @marcog Most editors - barring command line ones like vim - use the text widgets provided by their OS or windowing toolkit.

Comment: @IVlad marcog is right, you forget that simple multiplication in this case is not a constant-time operation. Only last multiplication makes it  `O(n)`, and exponentiation is likely `O(n^2)` (although, with small constant due to bit-packing).

Comment: @SB I wouldn't call it a winner: it relies on another solution to prove its correctness. You can't really do that on interview. Not to mention, they seem to have the same complexity. But anyway, +1 for the work done.

Answer (score 15):

Here's how I would approach it:

- assume <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> = select all
- assume <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> = copy selection
- assume <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> = paste copied selection

given some text, it takes 4 keystrokes to duplicate it:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to select it all
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy it
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste (this will paste over the selection - STATE YOUR ASSUMPTIONS)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste again which doubles it.

From there, you can consider doing 4 or 5 A's, then looping through the above.  Note that doing `ctrl + a, c, v, v` will grow your text exponentially as you loop through.  If remaining strokes < 4, just keep doing a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>

The key to interviews @ places like Google is to state your assumptions, and communicate your thinking.  they want to know how you solve problems.

Comment: Good point about interview technique, getting the correct answer is less important than communicating clearly in the end!

Comment: Good answer. For the algorithm, a greedy off-by-two error: `ACVV-VVVVV` multiplies by 7, `ACVV-ACVV-V` multiplies by 6. So Ctrl-V for remaining strokes < 6 instead of 4.

Answer (score 5):

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> is an advantage only after 4 'A's.

So I would do something like this (in pseudo-BASIC-code, since you haven't specified any proper language):

```
// We should not use the clipboard for the first four A's:
FOR I IN 1 TO MIN(N, 4)
    PRINT 'CLICK A'
NEXT
LET N1 = N - 4

// Generates the maximum number of pastes allowed:
FOR I IN 1 TO (N1 DIV 3) DO
    PRINT 'CTRL-A'
    PRINT 'CTRL-C'
    PRINT 'CTRL-V'
    LET N1 = N1 - 3
NEXT

// If we still have same keystrokes left, let's use them with simple CTRL-Vs
FOR I IN N1 TO N
    PRINT 'CTRL-V'
NEXT
```

**Edit**

1. Back to using a single <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> in the main loop.
2. Added some comments to explain what I'm trying to do here.
3. Fixed an issue with the "first four A's" block.

Comment: @SB: I'm doing the CTRL-V for the **LAST** pastes only. Which is exactly what you said in your answer, by the way. Which means we think similar, so I don't know why you're criticizing me - or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: google never specifies a proper language to write in, which ever you want.

Answer (score 5):

It's solveable in O(1): Like with the Fibonacci numbers, there is a formula to calculate the number of printed As (and the sequence of keystrokes):

---

1) We can simplify the problem description:

- Having only [A],[C-a]+[C-c],[C-v] and an empty copy-paste-buffer

equals

- having only [C-a]+[C-c],[C-v] and "A" in the copy-paste-buffer.

---

2) We can describe the sequence of keystrokes as a string of N chars out of {'*','V','v'}, where 'v' means [C-v] and '*' means [C-a] and 'V' means [C-c]. Example: "vvvv*Vvvvv*Vvvv"

The length of that string still equals N.

The product of the lengths of the Vv-words in that string equals the number of produced As.

---

3) Given a fixed length N for that string and a fixed number K of words, the outcome will be maximal iff all words have nearly equal lengths. Their pair-wise difference is not more than ±1.

Now, what is the optimal number K, if N is given?

---

4) Suppose, we want to increase the number of words by appending one single word of length L, then we have to reduce L+1 times any previous word by one 'v'. Example: "…*Vvvv*Vvvv*Vvvv*Vvvv" -> "…*Vvv*Vvv*Vvv*Vvv*Vvv"

Now, what is the optimal word length L?

(5*5*5*5*5) < (4*4*4*4*4)*4 , (4*4*4*4) > (3*3*3*3)*3

=> Optimal is L=4.

---

5) Suppose, we have a sufficient large N to generate a string with many words of length 4, but a few keystrokes are left; how should we use them?

- If there are 5 or more left: Append another word with length 4.
- If there are 0 left: Done.
- If there are 4 left: We could either

  a) append one word with length 3: 4*4*4*4*3=768.

  b) or increase 4 words to lenght 5: 5*5*5*5=625. => Appending one word is better.
- If there are 3 left:  We could either

  a) or append one word with length 3 by adjusting the previus word from length 4 to 3: 4*4*4*2=128 < 4*4*3*3=144.

  b) increase 3 words to lenght 5: 5*5*5=125. => Appending one word is better.
- If there are 2 left: We could either

  a) or append one word with length 3 by adjusting the previus two words from length 4 to 3: 4*4*1=16 < 3*3*3=27.

  b) increase 2 words to lenght 5: 5*5=25. => Appending one word is better.
- If there is 1 left: We could either

  a) or append one word with length 3 by adjusting the previus three words from length 4 to 3: 4*4*4*0=0 < 3*3*3*3=81.

  b) increase one word to lenght 5: 4*4*5=80. => Appending one word is better.

---

6) Now, what if we don't have a "sufficient large N" to use the rules in 5)? We have to stick with plan b), if possible!
The strings for small N are:

1:"v", 2:"vv", 3:"vvv", 4:"vvvv"

5:"vvvvv" → 5 **(plan b)**

6:"vvvvvv" → 6 **(plan b)**

7:"vvv*Vvv" → 9 (plan a)

8:"vvvv*Vvv" → 12 (plan a)

9:"vvvv*Vvvv" → 16

10:"vvvv*Vvvvv" → 20 **(plan b)**

11:"vvv*Vvv*Vvv" → 29 (plan a)

12:"vvvv*Vvv*Vvv" → 36 (plan a)

13:"vvvv*Vvvv*Vvv" → 48 (plan a)

14:"vvvv*Vvvv*Vvvv" → 64

15:"vvv*Vvv*Vvv*Vvv" → 81 (plan a)

…

---

7) Now, what is the optimal number K of words in a string of length N?

If N < 7 then K=1 else if 6 < N < 11 then K=2 ; otherwise: **K=ceil((N+1)/5)**

Written in C/C++/Java: `int K = (N<7)?(1) : (N<11)?(2) : ((N+5)/5);`

And if N > 10, then the number of words with length 3 will be: K*5-1-N. With this, we can calculate the number of printed As:

If N > 10, the number of As will be:  **4^{N+1-4K}·3^{5K-N-1}**

Comment: Seems to be right, works for the examples given by @Andrew's answer, but your answer is also O(log N) instead of O(1), right?

Comment: How could it be O(log N)? The mathematical formula to calculate the number of As is calculated in O(1). The algorithm to print the keystrokes is either O(N) because there are O(N) keystrokes to print, or O(1) iff you allow to print it as regular expression.

Comment: Calculating the exponentiation is O(log N) since the exponent on the 4 increases with N.  If you print out the number of As in factored form it is O(1).

Comment: Ah, OK. Never thought about actually computing the number with integer arithmetic. I'd be only interested in either the formula or a floating point approximation. But of course, to be able to compare it to other numbers, it would have to be calculated exact.

Answer (score 3):

It takes 3 keystrokes to double your number of As. It only makes sense to start doubling when you have 3 or more As already printed. You want your last allowed keystroke to be a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to make sure you are doubling the biggest number you can, so in order to align it we will fill in any extra keystrokes after the first three As at the beginning with more As.

```
for (i = 3 + n%3; i>0 && n>0; n--, i--) {
    print("a");
}

for (; n>0; n = n-3) {
    print("ctrl-a");
    print("ctrl-c");
    print("ctrl-v");
}
```

***Edit:***

This is terrible, I completely got ahead of myself and didn't consider multiple pastes for each copy.

***Edit 2:***

I believe pasting 3 times is optimal, when you have enough keystrokes to do it. In 5 keystrokes you multiply your number of As by 4. This is better than multiplying by 3 using 4 keystrokes and better than multiplying by 5 using 6 keystrokes. I compared this by giving each method the same number of keystrokes, enough so they each would finish a cycle at the same time (60), letting the 3-multiplier do 15 cycles, the 4-multiplier do 12 cycles, and the 5-multiplier do 10 cycles. 3^15 = 14,348,907, 4^12=16,777,216, and 5^10=9,765,625. If there are only 4 keystrokes left, doing a 3-multiplier is better than pasting 4 more times, essentially making the previous 4 multiplier become an 8-multiplier. If there are only 3 keystrokes left, a 2-multiplier is best.

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have x characters in the clipboard and x characters in the text area; let's call it "state x".

Let's press "Paste" a few times (i denote it by `m-1` for convenience), then "Select-all" and "Copy"; after this sequence, we get to "state m*x".
Here, we wasted a total of m+1 keystrokes.
So the asymptotic growth is (at least) something like `f^n`, where f = `m^(1/(m+1))`.
I believe it's the maximum possible asymptotic growth, though i cannot prove it (yet).

Trying various values of m shows that the maximum for f is obtained for `m=4`.

Let's use the following algorithm:

```
Press A a few times
Press Select-all
Press Copy
Repeat a few times:
    Press Paste
    Press Paste
    Press Paste
    Press Select-all
    Press Copy
While any keystrokes left:
    Press Paste
```

(not sure it's the optimal one).

The number of times to press A at the beginning is 3: if you press it 4 times, you miss the opportunity to double the number of A's in 3 more keystrokes.

The number of times to press Paste at the end is no more than 5: if you have 6 or more keystrokes left, you can use Paste, Paste, Paste, Select-all, Copy, Paste instead.

So, we get the following algorithm:

```
If (less than 6 keystrokes - special case)
    While (any keystrokes left)
        A
Else
    First 5 keystrokes: A, A, A, Select-all, Copy
    While (more than 5 keystrokes left)
        Paste, Paste, Paste, Select-all, Copy
    While (any keystrokes left)
        Paste
```

(not sure it's the optimal one). The number of characters after executing this is something like

`3 * pow(4, floor((n - 6) / 5)) * (2 + (n - 1) % 5)`.

Sample values: 1,2,3,4,5,6,9,12,15,18,24,36,48,60,72,96,144,192,240,288,...

Answer (score 2):

What follows uses the OP's second edit that pasting does **not** replace existing text.

Notice a few things:

- ^A and ^C can be considered a single action that takes two keystrokes, since it never makes sense to do them individually. In fact, we can replace all instances of ^A^C with ^K^V, where ^K is a *one-key* "cut" operation (let's abbreviate it X). We shall see that dealing with ^K is much nicer than the two-cost ^A^C.
- Let's assume that an 'A' starts in the clipboard. Then ^V (let's abbreviate it Y) is strictly superior to A and we can drop the latter from all consideration. (In the actual problem, if the clipboard starts empty, in what follows we'll just replace Y with A instead of ^V up until the first X.)

Every reasonable keystroke sequence can thus be interpreted as a group of Ys separated by Xs, for example YYYXYXYYXY. Denote by V(s) the number of 'A's produced by the sequence s. Then V(nXm) = V(n)*V(m), because X essentially replaces every Y in m with V(n) 'A's.

The copy-paste problem is thus isomorphic to the following problem: "using m+1 numbers which sum to N-m, maximimze their product." For example, when N=6, the answer is m=1 and the numbers (2,3). 6 = 2*3 = V(YYXYYY) = V(AA^A^C^V^V) (or V(YYYXYY) = V(AAA^A^C^V). )

We can make a few observations:

For a *fixed* value of `m`, the numbers to choose are `ceil( (N-m)/(m+1) )` and `floor( (N-m)/(m+1) )` (in whatever combination makes the sum work out; more specifically you will need `(N-m) % (m+1)` `ceils` and the rest `floor`s). This is because, for `a < b`, `(a+1)*(b-1) >= a*b`.

Unfortunately I don't see an easy way to find the value of `m`. If this were my interview I would propose two solutions at this point:

Option 1. Loop over all possible `m`. An O(`n log n`) solution.

C++ code:

```
long long ipow(int a, int b)
{
  long long val=1;
  long long mul=a;

  while(b>0)
    {
      if(b%2)
    val *= mul;
      mul *= mul;
      b/=2;
    }
  return val;
}

long long trym(int N, int m)
{
  int floor = (N-m)/(m+1);
  int ceil = 1+floor;
  int numceils = (N-m)%(m+1);
  return ipow(floor, m+1-numceils) * ipow(ceil, numceils);
}

long long maxAs(int N)
{
  long long maxval=0;
  for(int m=0; m<N; m++)
    {
      maxval = std::max(maxval, trym(N,m));
    }
  return maxval;
}
```

Option 2. Allow `m` to attain non-integer values and find its optimal value by taking the derivative of `[(N-m)/(m+1)]^m` with respect to `m` and solving for its root. There is no analytic solution, but the root can be found using e.g. Newton's method. Then use the floor and ceiling of that root for the value of `m`, and choose whichever is best.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int dp(int n) 
{
    int arr[] = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = i + 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < n - 3; i++) 
    {
        int numchars = arr[i] * 2;
        int j = i + 3;
        arr[j] = Math.max(arr[j], numchars);
        while (j < n - 1) 
        {
            numchars = numchars + arr[i];
            arr[++j] = Math.max(arr[j], numchars);
        }
    }
    return arr[n - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach and solution with code below.

**Approach:**

There are three distinct operations that can be performed.

1. *Keystroke A* - Outputs one character 'A'
2. *Keystroke (Ctrl-A) + (Ctrl-C)* - Outputs nothing essentially. These two keystrokes can be combined into one operation because each of these keystrokes individually make no sense. Also, this keystroke sets up the output for the next paste operation.
3. *Keystroke (Ctrl-V)* - Output for this keystroke really depends on the previous (second) operation and hence we would need to account for that in our code.

Now given the three distinct operations and their respective outputs, we have to run through all the permutations of these operations.

---

**Assumption:**

Now, some version of this problem states that the sequence of keystrokes, Ctrl+A -> Ctrl+C -> Ctrl+V, overwrite the highlighted selection. To factor in this assumption, only one line of code needs to be added to the solution below where the printed variable in case 2 is set to 0

```
        case 2:
        //Ctrl-A and then Ctrl-C
            if((count+2) < maxKeys)
            {
                pOutput = printed;

                //comment the below statement to NOT factor 
                //in the assumption described above
                printed = 0;    
            }
```

For this solution

The code below will print a couple of sequences and the last sequence is the correct answer for any given N. e.g. for N=11 this will be the correct sequence

**With the assumption**

A, A, A, A, A, C, S, V, V, V, V, :20:

**Without the assumption**

A, A, A, C, S, V, V, C, S, V, V, :27:

> I have decided to retain the assumption for this solution.

---

**Keystroke Legend:**

'A' - A

'C' - Ctrl+A

'S' - Ctrl+C

'V' - Ctrl+V

---

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void maxAprinted(int count, int maxKeys, int op, int printed, int pOutput, int *maxPrinted, char *seqArray)
{
    if(count > maxKeys)
        return;

    if(count == maxKeys)
    {
        if((*maxPrinted) < printed)
        {
            //new sequence found which is an improvement over last sequence
            (*maxPrinted) = printed;

            printf("\n");
            int i;
            for(i=0; i<maxKeys; i++)
                printf(" %c,",seqArray[i]);
        }

        return;
    }

    switch(op)
    {
        case 1:
        //A keystroke
            printed++;

            seqArray[count] = 'A';
            count++;
            break;

        case 2:
        //Ctrl-A and then Ctrl-C
            if((count+2) < maxKeys)
            {
                pOutput = printed;

                //comment the below statement to NOT factor 
                //in the assumption described above
                printed = 0;    
            }

            seqArray[count] = 'C';
            count++;
            seqArray[count] = 'S';
            count++;
            break;

        case 3:
        //Ctrl-V
            printed = printed + pOutput;

            seqArray[count] = 'V';
            count++;
            break;
    }

    maxAprinted(count, maxKeys, 1, printed, pOutput, maxPrinted, seqArray);
    maxAprinted(count, maxKeys, 2, printed, pOutput, maxPrinted, seqArray);
    maxAprinted(count, maxKeys, 3, printed, pOutput, maxPrinted, seqArray);    
}

int main()
{
    const int keyStrokes = 11;

    //this array stores the sequence of keystrokes
    char *sequence;
    sequence = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(keyStrokes + 1));

    //stores the max count for As printed for a sqeuence
    //updated in the recursive call.
    int printedAs = 0;

    maxAprinted(0, keyStrokes,  1, 0, 0, &printedAs, sequence);

    printf(" :%d:", printedAs);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the tricks mentioned in answers above, Mathematically, Solution can be explained in one equation as,

4 + 4^[(N-4)/5] + ((N-4)%5)*4^[(N-4)/5].
where [] is greatest integer factor

Answer (score 0):

There is a trade-off between printing m-A's manually, then using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and N-m-2 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. The best solution is in the middle. If max key strokes = 10, the best solution is typing 5 A's or 4 A's.

try using this Look at this http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-print-maximum-number-of-a-using-given-four-keys/ and maybe optimize a bit looking for the results around the mid point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with dynamic programming, without a nested loop, and which also prints the actual characters that you'd need to type:

```
N = 52

count = [0] * N
res = [[]] * N
clipboard = [0] * N

def maybe_update(i, new_count, new_res, new_clipboard):
  if new_count > count[i] or (
      new_count == count[i] and new_clipboard > clipboard[i]):
    count[i] = new_count
    res[i] = new_res
    clipboard[i] = new_clipboard

for i in range(1, N):
  # First option: type 'A'.
  # Using list concatenation for 'res' to avoid O(n^2) string concatenation.
  maybe_update(i, count[i - 1] + 1, res[i - 1] + ['A'], clipboard[i - 1])

  # Second option: type 'CTRL+V'.
  maybe_update(i, count[i - 1] + clipboard[i - 1],  res[i - 1] + ['v'],
               clipboard[i - 1])

  # Third option: type 'CTRL+A, CTRL+C, CTRL+V'.
  # Assumption: CTRL+V always appends.
  if i >= 3:
    maybe_update(i, 2 * count[i - 3],  res[i - 3] + ['acv'], count[i - 3])

for i in range(N):
  print '%2d %7d %6d %-52s' % (i, count[i], clipboard[i], ''.join(res[i]))
```

This is the output ('a' means 'CTRL+A', etc.)

```
 0       0      0                                                     
 1       1      0 A                                                   
 2       2      0 AA                                                  
 3       3      0 AAA                                                 
 4       4      0 AAAA                                                
 5       5      0 AAAAA                                               
 6       6      3 AAAacv                                              
 7       9      3 AAAacvv                                             
 8      12      3 AAAacvvv                                            
 9      15      3 AAAacvvvv                                           
10      18      9 AAAacvvacv                                          
11      27      9 AAAacvvacvv                                         
12      36      9 AAAacvvacvvv                                        
13      45      9 AAAacvvacvvvv                                       
14      54     27 AAAacvvacvvacv                                      
15      81     27 AAAacvvacvvacvv                                     
16     108     27 AAAacvvacvvacvvv                                    
17     135     27 AAAacvvacvvacvvvv                                   
18     162     81 AAAacvvacvvacvvacv                                  
19     243     81 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvv                                 
20     324     81 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvv                                
21     405     81 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvvv                               
22     486    243 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacv                              
23     729    243 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvv                             
24     972    243 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvv                            
25    1215    243 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvvv                           
26    1458    729 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacv                          
27    2187    729 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvv                         
28    2916    729 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvv                        
29    3645    729 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvvv                       
30    4374   2187 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacv                      
31    6561   2187 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvv                     
32    8748   2187 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvv                    
33   10935   2187 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvvv                   
34   13122   6561 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacv                  
35   19683   6561 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvv                 
36   26244   6561 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvv                
37   32805   6561 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvvv               
38   39366  19683 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacv              
39   59049  19683 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvv             
40   78732  19683 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvv            
41   98415  19683 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvvv           
42  118098  59049 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacv          
43  177147  59049 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvv         
44  236196  59049 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvv        
45  295245  59049 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvvv       
46  354294 177147 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacv      
47  531441 177147 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvv     
48  708588 177147 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvv    
49  885735 177147 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvvv   
50 1062882 531441 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacv  
51 1594323 531441 AAAacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvvacvv
```

Answer (score 0):

If N key Strokes are allowed, then the result is N-3.

A's ->  N-3

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> -> Selecting those N Characters   :+1

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> -> Copying those N Characters     :+1

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> -> Pasting the N Characters.      :+1
i.e., (Since we have selected the whole characters using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) Replacing  these existing N-3 characters with the copied N-3 Characters(which is overriding the same characters) and the result is N-3.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Learn how to add [content formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) and possibly use the actual arrow symbol `→`. This will improve the readability of your answer!