# Find the optimum sequence of keyboard hits to produce the most repeated characters

Tags: sequence

You are provided with four possible operations that can be done on the editor (each operation requires *one* keyboard hit).

1. A
2. Ctrl+A
3. Ctrl+C
4. Ctrl+V

Now you can hit the keyboard **N** times and you need to find the maximum number of *A*'s that can be printed. Also print the sequence of keyboard hits.

Comment: Sounds like some make work question that you find in AP Math classes.

Comment: This is Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606984/maximum-number-of-characters-using-keystrokes-a-ctrla-ctrlc-and-ctrlv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googled for the answer:

http://podlipensky.com/post/2011/02/07/Sundays-puzzle.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Off of the top of my head...

A single `A` followed by iterations of `Ctrl+A` `Ctrl+C` `Ctrl+V` `Ctrl+V`, where each iteration doubles the size of the text, starting at 1 character, then 2, then 4, then 8, etc.

So given N keystrokes, you can produce at most 2<sup>(N-1)/4</sup> characters.

I suspect that this is not the optimal (minimal) number of keystrokes, though. (I have not yet read the answer posted by @David.)