# Input as many characters as possible in notepad with fewest keyboard typings

Tags: string, algorithm

In windows notepad (or any other classic text editor), input a character need one keyboard typing, select-all,copy and paste need two(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>).

Note:we can use arrow keys to cancel the select all.

We can input `"aaaaaaaa"` with 8 simple typings `a`.

Or we can input `"aa"` first (cost 2 typing), and select all, then copy and paste 4 times(Why 4 times not 3 times? Because we don't cancel the select. You can simulate it in notepad). It will cost `2 + 5 * 2 = 12` typing in total.

My question is, for inputting n characters, how to find the shortest typing sequence?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606984/maximum-number-of-characters-using-keystrokes-a-ctrla-ctrlc-and-ctrlv?rq=1

Comment: This is not a practical programming question.

Comment: @RaymondChen:  Dynamic programming isn't a practical programming problem?  Really?   Take a look at the link Ziyao provided; it's quite practical, and even more interesting.

Comment: Dynamic programming is practical. Finding the minimum number of keystrokes to type the letter "a" into Notepad is not. Just press the letter a as many times as you need.