# N number of smileys using minimum keystrokes

Tags: algorithm

This is an interview question, i wasn't able to solve myself. Can somebody she some light?

Question: Assume you have chat client, in the text box you have one smiley (it's already there). Now you want that smiley N times and only two operations are allowed Copy and Paste. Result must be N smileys no more no less. Copy is basically ^a + ^c. You always have to copy all the smiley that are there in text box at a given time. Copy is one keystroke and paste is one keystroke. Write a algorithm / program for this problem. What will be the complexity?

Comment: Similar to [Maximum number of characters using keystrokes A, Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4606984). Perhaps you can apply some of the logic there to make an effort here.

Comment: More formally, is it accurate to say that we start with `result = ":)"; clipboard = "";` and that copy is `clipboard = result;` and that paste is `result += clipboard;`?

Comment: @KenWhite The questions are superficially similar, but the solution techniques don't have much more in common than dynamic programming on a similar state space.

Comment: @David: Yes, I'm aware they're only similar, which is why I didn't vote to close as a duplicate. The thought process for solving them is similar (although not the same, clearly) IMO. (It's definitely a better starting point than just posting the problem here and waiting for others to answer it for you.)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: Yes.

Comment: `Copy is basically ^a + ^c` is this part of the question or your assumption i.e. can I copy only 1 smile out of `m` smiles?

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie: It is a part of question. You can not copy 1 smile out of m smiles.

Answer (score 5):

Whatever the number of smileys N is, factor N into a product of primes. Then for each prime p in the factorization you need to do one copy and p-1 pastes. This is the minimal number of operations possible if "copy" means that you have to copy the entire string of smileys. The total number of operations is the sum of all the prime factors in the factorization of N.

Answer (score 2):

[user2566092's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25329745/2144669) is correct, but the statement

> This is the minimal number of operations possible

is claimed without proof. Here's a formal justification.

Let n be the target number of smileys. A configuration (r, k) consists of the number r of smileys in the result and the number k of smileys on the clipboard. The initial configuration is (1, 0). From (r, k), the configurations (r, r) [copy] and (r + k, k) [paste] are reachable in one keystroke.

The following lemma implies that, after a copy, the number of smileys in the result divides n evenly.

**Lemma** Suppose that g divides both r and k (g|r and g|k). Every configuration (r', k') reachable from (r, k) satisfies g|r' and g|k'.

**Proof** by induction. If the next step is a copy, to (r, r), then g|r and g|r. If the next step is a paste, to (r + k, k), then g|r + k and g|k.

Now we can prove the main claim.

**Theorem** The minimum number of steps from (1, 0) to some (n, k) where k is arbitrary is p1 + p2 + ... + pm, where n = p1 p2 ... pm is a prime factorization.

**Proof** user2566092 covered the upper bound: for i from 1 to m, copy once and paste pi - 1 times. The lower bound is obvious when n = 1. Otherwise, the best first action clearly is a copy, to (1, 1). We show by induction that the minimum number of steps from (1, 1) to (n, k) is p1 + p2 + ... + pm - 1.

From (1, 1), by the lemma, all we can do is paste until r divides n. Fix a particular r|n. The best action sequences from (r, r) to (n, n) and from (1, 1) to (n/r, n/r) clearly are the same. Without loss of generality by permuting the primes, assume that r = p1 p2 ... pj. Since a b >= a + b for a, b >= 2, we have r >= p1 + p2 + ... + pj. If r < n, then the total cost, by the inductive hypothesis, is at least r + pj+1 + pj+2 + ... + pm - 1 >= p1 + p2 + ... + pj - 1. If r = n, then the total cost is n - 1 >= p1 + p2 + ... + pm - 1.

Comment: You're right, I should have given a proof, because as your exposition shows, the proof is a bit lengthy. +1 for covering it entirely. =)

Answer (score 0):

2 * 2log(N).
Each time duplicate everything, until you don't need the complete set anymore. Then you could duplicate only part of the list.

E.g. 7 smileys:

1 copy everything

2 copy everything

4 copy only 3

Have 7.

Comment: This is not the optimal way to build up the largest number of smileys in the shortest number of operations. Consider if you have 6 operations. Your approach would double 3 times, giving 8 smileys and using 6 operations. However if you copy-paste-paste and then copy-paste-paste again you still use 6 operations but you get 9 smileys.

Comment: Complexity is an upper bound :)

Answer (score 0):

The program for the above problem is given below. The time complexity of this solution is O(n) in worst case. The worst case occurs when the given number is prime.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int smiles;
    cin>>smiles;
    int ans=0; 
    for(int i=2;i<=smiles;i++)
    { 
        while(smiles%i==0)
        { 
            ans+=i; 
            smiles/=i; 
        } 
    } 
    cout<<ans<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```